# Finalizing Saga on exception

Tags: c#, .net, masstransit, automatonymous

I've created a saga and was wondering how to handle my exceptions during the execution of activities. Ideally, I would like to kill off that saga instance in some cases, immediately in the `.Catch()`.

I've stumbled upon this thread: [Understanding "Finalize" in MassTransit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45847673/understanding-finalize-in-masstransit), my current approach is slightly different. In the `.Catch()` I publish a `SagaFaultedEvent` and transition to a `Faulted` state:

```
.Catch<Exception>(e => e
    .Publish(context => (ISagaFaultedEvent)new SagaFaultedEvent(context.Instance.Id))
    .TransitionTo(Faulted)));
```

Then handle this event by logging the issue and finalizing the instance

```
During(Faulted,
    When(SagaFaulted)
        .Activity(x => x.OfInstanceType<LogFaultedSagaActivity>())
        .Finalize());
```

This seems to work, however, in the answer to the mentioned thread, Chris says that the saga should be finalized directly there in the `Catch()`, however, there's no `Finalize()` available on the `ExceptionActivityBinder` and I don't have access to the `EventActivityBinder` there.

Am I missing something here (probably)? Is it possible to finalize the Saga directly in the `Catch()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for this was added to `Automatonymous` in 3.6.1, which was released today.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that was a quick fix!